# What is the use of "hmcIndexField" in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I noticed that some attributes contain within their definition a hmc custom property:

```
<custom-properties>
    <property name="hmcIndexField">
        <value>"thefield"</value>
    </property>
</custom-properties>
```

Can someone explain why is this custom property needed and when should it be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an deprecated attribute for hmc search configuration. You can find all information here:

[Lucene Search HMC Hybris4](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/Lucene+Search+-+End+User+Guide)

In common the page says that you can define customized searches in the hmc. With this property you define which attributes will be searchable wit the LuceneSearch.

[image: LuceneSearch]

[image: types]

[image: attributes]